# Why is first HQL query taking longer than other queries?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I am benchmarking JDBC and Hibernate (with JPA) performance and run the same queries several times in a row. I have noticed that the first query (Both with JDBC and Hibernate) runs longer than others.

I have disabled mysql cache, so i do believe it should not be mysql specific. Could it be?
I also clear EntityManager between each (HQL) query.

Could someone point me why the first query takes longer than others?

Log: http://pastebin.com/fwNbqaMD

Thank you for your responses

Comment: Did you kill and restart your application between tests?

Comment: @Kukmedis: Did any of the answers provide any help??

Comment: @phresnel No. I'm writing my final bachelor thesis and could not write guesses on this issue. I know that those guesses may be true, but I need to back them with arguments literature etc

Comment: Erm, ..., perhaps the answers give you hints on where to reasearch next? Sounds to me like you are expecting fully qualified thesis fragments without wanting to research more on yourself. Have you even looked beyond the topics mentioned in the answers?

Comment: @phresnel actually i tried searching the web before asking. Now that i have finished my thesis, I have of course looked up literature (so I can back my arguments). I have been nervous writing my thesis (deadline) when I wrote last comment. Sorry :)

Comment: @Kukmedis: Not a problem. We all get nervous at some point :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess because of runtime optimizations on your program.

During each run, profiling information of your code is collected, and the JIT optimizer applies optimizations.

Comment: I looked up HotSpot whitepapers and found out that the first time code bluck is ran, it is compiled before. I think that was the reason for the first query of test to run slower

Comment: I once did some benchmarking of some Java code I wrote. To make it a serious benchmark, I either warmed it by running it 10 times before taking the time, or when comparing different algorithms I tested only one algorithm per run.

Comment: If I would test desktop app, then yes, it would be wise to mix algorithms, but I test server app, which may have 1 month uptime and I guess it would always run compiled code. Sun actually stated that JIT is way more needed on server apps

Comment: But when performance-testing, JIT may really bias the results, server or not, so always make sure to make many tests :)

Answer (score 1):

Following can be few possible reasons.

1. Connection pooling.
2. Prepared statements.
3. DB engine warm up / init.

In either cases the first iteration will have more to do than rest.

For example, for prepared statements query plan is built for first time and cached for reuse in subsequent executions.

Comment: Connection pooling was the reason for the very first query